# SQL joining two tables with the same column names

Tags: sql, join, sas

I have two datasets that have the exact same column names.

However, when I run the following code,

```
proc sql;
create table diff as 
select a.fish, b.fish
from newmonth as a 
left join previousmonth as b
on a.pond = b.pond;
quit;
```

It only returns a table with one column, being fish. However, I would want two columns, a.fish and b.fish.

I **don't** want to use select a.fish **as** , since I have about 50 different animals I want to select and don't want to manually type as in each time.

Is there a way for SQL to automatically label the columns based on which table it is from?

Thanks,

Comment: The is no SQL syntax that does what you want without **as**.  You can use macro and table metadata to create the SQL statements you might want.  However, such a join seems to be for the purpose of reporting or tabulating.  You can **stack** the data and at the same time create a new variable whose values correspond to the row source table.  After stacking `Proc TABULATE` can be used.

Comment: That code returns a table with 2 columns, both called fish; it cannot "return a table with one column". Give a [mre]. Clearly ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate questions & don't include things not necessary for asking it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query and check the result:

```
proc sql;
create table diff as 
select *
from newmonth as a 
left join previousmonth as b
on a.pond = b.pond;
quit;
```

Comment: Hey! Doesn't seem to work unfortunately, it returns the same number of columns as the dataset rather than double the number of columns

Answer (score 0):

Give them different names:

```
create table diff as 
    select a.fish as a_fish, b.fish as b_fish
    from newmonth a left join
         previousmonth b
         on a.pond = b.pond;
```